# Tables search in django

Tags: python, django

Here is my models structure .

```
class  Category(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class SUBCategory(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cat       = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name = 'scat',null = True,blank=True)

class Tags(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class FullProfile(models.Model):
    user            = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday        = models.DateField(null = True,blank=True)
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True,blank=True)
    middle_name     = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True,blank=True)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True,blank=True)
    token           = models.CharField (max_length=200,null = True,blank=True)
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True,blank=True)
    tags            = models.ManyToManyField(Tags,related_name = 'tg',null = True,blank=True)
    category        = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name = 'cat',null = True,blank=True)
    facebook_url    = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True,blank=True)
    twitter_url     = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True,blank=True)
    mobile          = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True,blank=True)
    landline        = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True,blank=True)
    country         = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices = COUNTRIES,null=True,blank =True,default='INDIA')
    state           = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True,blank=True)
    city            = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True,blank=True)
```

Basically a user can belong to a category and subcategory .

I am looking for a way to search for a user who belongs to a particular category ,subcategory or tags ,

I am just trying with basic thing like

```
get_all = FullProfile.objects.filter(
                       Q(category__id__iexact=cat) |
                       Q(user__username__icontains=keyword) |
                       Q(first_name__icontains=keyword)
                        ).distinct()
```

Please tell me better way to make this search module effective .Since someone else is going to manage this app so i don't want to use Haystack for this small search .

Comment: How many fields do you need to search on? The way you're doing it is fine unless you need to query a dynamic set of fields each time.

Comment: based on tags keyword which matches fir_name or user name category sub category and tags

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to search based on those 3 fields, then you're doing it fine. If the table grows large, you should probably create an index on the fields being searched as long as the index is able to be used with a `LIKE` SQL statement.

If the set of potential fields grow large, consider using something like [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) to do the filtering with forms.